# Creating a Line Graph in D3 using XML

Tags: javascript, xml, d3.js

I am trying to create a line graph using D3. The data for the graph is stored in an XML file like this:

**XML Code:**

```
<record>
    <date_value>1376092800000</date_value>
</record>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
var record=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("record");

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.xml("values.xml", "application/xml", function(data) {
    for(var d = 0; d < record.length; d++){
        d.date = parseDate(record[d].getElementsByTagName("date_value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        d.close += 1;
};

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")  
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});
```

I'm having trouble with the part where I get the data. The x value is the date value and the y value should be increased by one each time. With the current code I have no errors, but only the y axis is showing with no data. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your for loop? Currently, you're just modifying `d`, which you immediately overwrite. Seems like that's a mistake.

Comment: @Mike I am trying to step through the number of records in my XML file, but I also need to pass in `d`. Looking at it some more, I understand what you are saying that I'm declaring a value that I just overwrite, so I need a way to pass in `d` and step through a for loop. Also, the `data.forEach(function(d)` does not work.